# Is ViewAnnotation implemented in MapLibre or Not?

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

Is `ViewAnnotation` integrated in `maplibre` SDK or not ?
if No then what is alternative way to do same?

I want to display label on each features(can be line/point/polygon) added to the layer.

I tried to find it in it's [repository on github](https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-native) but couldn't get anything related to it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to display label on each Feature using MapLibre SDK.
How can i achieve this functionality ?